# How can I arrange my grid into a variable?

Tags: python, list, variables

So I wrote a code that yields a grid with the help of some helpful stackoverflow users, and here it is..

```
import random
import string

for x in range(4):
    for y in range(4):
        print( '['+random.choice(string.ascii_letters)+']',end='' )
    print()
```

Now I want to store the grid in a variable x. I tried doing so like this..

```
import random
import string

for x in range(4):
    for y in range(4):
        x = print( '['+random.choice(string.ascii_letters)+']',end='' )
    print(x)
```

but the output yields

```
[P][y][l][V]None
[c][U][f][m]None
[j][s][x][c]None
[G][v][R][X]None
```

How can I make the output only print out the letters without 'None' at the end of each line AS WELL AS store the grid in variable x?

Comment: btw, you won't be able to store your letters in `x` while you continue to use it as a loop variable. Did you mean you want to store the letters in something like `z`?

Comment: `print()` doesn't return anything, that's why you get `None`.

Answer (score 1):

`print()` just prints its arguments, it doesn't return the string that it printed. So you're setting `x` to `None`.

Don't print the strings, concatenate them onto a variable.

```
import random
import string

result = ''

for x in range(4):
    for y in range(4):
        result += f'[{random.choice(string.ascii_letters)}]'
    result += '\n'

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. Maybe using a numpy grid helps.

```py
import string
import random
import numpy as np

grid = np.zeros((4,4), dtype=str)
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        grid[i,j] = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
print(grid)
```